# How can I parallelize the mapping of a list?

Tags: java, concurrency

This is the problem I have: I have a large sequence of some objects (`List<SomeClass>`), and want to perform some operation on all elements of list and get a new sequence (`List<SomeOtherClass>`).

Like:

```
List<SomeOtherClass> list = new ArrayList<SomeOtherClass>();
for(SomeClass sc : originalList) 
  list.add(someOperation(sc));
```

Since operation `someOperation` does not have any side effects, and the list is quite large, I want this mapping operation to be parallelized.

What will be the best way to do that in Java?

Answer (score 4):

A possible implementation can utilize the [Executor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) framework (example included).

Comment: If you are going to introduce concurrency, I would highly recommend using the Executor framework. It takes quite a few of the headaches away.

Answer (score 1):

Use threading and partition your work using sublists.

Answer (score 1):

Split the input list, and use FutureTask task, then merge the results

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I usually do it:

```
// Somewhere define a static final int NUM_THREADS that is appropriate.

ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( NUM_THREADS );
// There are other options: look at what the Executors class has to offer.

List<SomeOtherClass> list = new ArrayList<SomeOtherClass>();

List<Future<SomeOtherClass>> list = new ArrayList<Future<SomeOtherClass>>();

for( SomeClass sc : originalList )
    futures.add( submit( new someOperation( sc ) ) );

for( Future<SomeOtherClass> future : futures )
    list.add( future.get() ); // Again, see the docs, you can also set a timeout.

exec.shutdown(); // Important. Otherwise the threads stay alive.
```

`someOperation` is then defined as a callable

```
class someOperation extends Callable<SomeOtherClass> {

    private SomeClass input;

    public someOperation( SomeClass input ){
        this.input = input;
    }

    public SomeOtherClass call(){
        // Do your operation on 'input' here
    }
}
```

Note: I didn't have any `try`-`catch` blocks here, but you will have to have some. `shutdown` should be in the `finally` block. I just don't remember what throws what ATM, your IDE should help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

Doug Lea's [jsr166y](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/concurrency-interest/) includes the Fork/Join framework, which is perfect for this kind of thing. It is designed for parallel decomposition of CPU intensive jobs such as this, and is very efficient at it.

Probably the easiest way to use it though is with the new Scala 2.9 [parallel collections](http://www.scala-notes.org/2011/05/scala-2-9-parallel-collections-for-mandelactors/) as it completely abstracts away its use (to get a parallel collection in Scala you just add `.par` to the end).

Both solutions have many tutorials and examples available though Google.